# limit of $\frac{1-\sin x+\cos x }{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

how can i show that
$$\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{1-\sin \:x\:+\cos \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=-1$$

$$\left(\frac{1-\sin \:x\:+\cos \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=\left(\frac{1+\cos \:x -\sin x}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)$$
any help thanks

Comment: It's the same as $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\cos y-\sin y}y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac\pi2-x=2y$  using $\sin2y=2\sin y\cos y,\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y$

$$\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{1-\sin \:x\:+\cos \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=-\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos2y+\sin2y}{2y}$$

$$=-\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin y}y\cdot\lim_{y\to0}(\sin y+\cos y)=?$$

Comment: = -1.(1).1=-1 thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start changing $x=\frac \pi 2+y$ making
$$\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{1-\sin \:x\:+\cos \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=\lim _{y\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\sin (y)-\cos (y)}{y}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{1-\sin \:x\:+\cos \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=\\
\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{1-\sin \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)+\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{\cos \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=\\
\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})-\sin x}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)+\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}- x)}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=\\
\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{2\sin(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{2}).\cos(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+x}{2})}{-(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)}\right)+\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}- x)}{-(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)}\right)=\\$$
so $$2(\frac{1}{-2})\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\cos(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+x}{2})+\underbrace{\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}- x)}{-(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)}\right)}_{-1}=\\-1(0)+(-1)=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting to notice that even if you want to solve it with L'Hospital,in this case you can but it would suggest not to use the L'hospital method for limits of this form.

$\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{1-\sin \:x\:+\cos \:x\:}{x-\frac{\pi }{2}}\right)=\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}-\frac{(\sin{x}-\cos{x})-1}{x -\frac{\pi}{2}}=-\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{f(x)-f(\frac{\pi}{2})}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=-f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=-1$

where $f(x)=\sin{x}-\cos{x}$

Comment: If you had looked into "Tags" section, you would have looked that Yacob, does not need for a proof with L'Hospital rule.

Comment: @luli if you had read carefully my answer you would have seen that  that i did not use L'Hospital and i mentioned also tha it cannot be used..i just use the definition of derivative..

Comment: Sorry, but please explain me, why L'Hospital rule can not be used?

Comment: Because using L'Hospital's rule in such limit is just a circular reasoning...because  this limit is in a form where you must compute the derivative at $\pi/2$ not use it a priori when applying the L'Hospital's rule

Comment: yes, you are right. now I have wrote down the exercise and I have observed that your reason is true. Sorry, I'm wrong.

Comment: It's ok..Just note tha someone must be careful in such limits if he wants to apply L'Hospital's rule....this not a very nice method of computing limits,but i also posted it for the O.P to see why L'Hospital rule fails

Comment: I disagree it's circular reasoning. Once you *know* that the derivative of the sine is the cosine, there's nothing wrong in using it for computations. Besides, the analytic definition of sine with its Taylor series allows to compute the derivative without using $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, which is instead a consequence.

Comment: @egreg i do not know about the analytic definition of sine or cosine..but it is a circular reasoning to use L'Hospital